# How to design type table with indefinite multiple items?

Tags: mysql

I want to design an invoice system. In invoice table there should be an `invoice_type`, which comes from a table called `invoice_type_table`. I am confused with the structure of this `invoice_type_table`. How should I design it for multiple billing item?

Billing_item_table

```
+--+----+------+
|id|name|amount|
+--+----+------+
| 1| A  |   500|
+--+----+------+
| 2| B  |   320|
+--+----+------+
```

Suppose in `invoice_type` table I want two type of invoice like typeone with billing item `A and B`, and in typetwo with just billing item `A`. any solution to avoid junction table is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but can't you just juse the table with types and an use a one to many connection on billing_item? So:

```
billing_item
+--+----+------+-----+
|id|name|amount|type |
+--+----+------+-----+
| 1| A  |   500|  1  |
+--+----+------+-----+
| 2| B  |   320|  2  |
+--+----+------+-----+


[many to one connection]

invoice_type:
+--+----+
|id|name|
+--+----+
| 1|name| 
+--+----+
| 2|name|
+--+----+
```

In this case you can give every billing item one type. The "type" column in "billing_item" contains the id of the row in "invoice_type". If you want to be able to give them multiple types, you need a junction table.

EDIT:
When a billing_item can have more than one invoice type, use a junction table:

```
billing_item
+--+----+------+-----+
|id|name|amount|type |
+--+----+------+-----+
| 1| A  |   500|  1  |
+--+----+------+-----+
| 2| B  |   320|  2  |
+--+----+------+-----+


[one to many connection]

billing_invoice_types:
+----------+---------------+
|billing_id|invoice_type_id|
+----------+---------------+
| 1        |       1       |
+----------+---------------+
| 2        |       1       |
+----------+---------------+
| 2        |       2       |
+----------+---------------+

[many to one connection]

invoice_type:
+--+----+
|id|name|
+--+----+
| 1|name| 
+--+----+
| 2|name|
+--+----+
```

Comment: for type 1 assign A and B both and for type 2 assign just B in your way

Comment: if i need a one type with one item then i wouldn't ask. very annoying answer, and you are editing it twice a minute. first understand then answer.

Comment: I guess I understood it now, check my answer. In my opinion you need a junction table.

Comment: before understanding the question u answered and edit it three times. This not acceptable way to answer question.

Comment: First, I appreciate you're telling how I can do things better, but you can't just KEEP telling me I do things wrong, rather than telling me I gave you the right answer or not. I'm doing my best to HELP you, you know... And there is a "edited...." link below my answer, where you can see my changes. I just keep the post clean.

Comment: @PaulWhite Not acceptable is answering before understanding the question. Because you probably going to miss the point .You may edit, improve or update your answer.

Comment: @PaulWhite LOL, and you are accusing me for not asking properly. If it is so, nothing justifies answering before understanding

Comment: @Alvi_1987 there is nothing wrong with answering questions, whether they are clear or not or whether one understands them perfectly or not. That's why we have the edit button. And that's how the upvote/downvote system is for and will take care of poor answers. Many questions are far from clear and no one except the OP can perfectly understand them.

Comment: Edited my answer for newcomers, so they understand my answer more clearly. The text around and inside the code object, didn't fit together.